# Moving an ASP site

Tags: asp-classic

First let me say i never dealt with ASP before so i think its an easy fix but again, im a noob. I was asked to move a site from one location to another. When i did, i noticed that when i loaded the site in the new location, i would just see raw code. Obviously that's bad so I did a little investigation and it turns out i needed a Windows server. I went and got one. I re-uploaded the files to the new server and it partly works.

this is the original one(location i mean)
http://www.lesbijoux.com/

And this is the same site on the new server.
http://lesbijoux.com.previewdns.com/

although it comes up, there are visually 3 errors on the site (2 up top and one in the footer)

plus, the footer links don't work.

I copied all contents from the old server to the new server as is so that said, all the files **should** be the same in both places. When i click the footer links on the new non-working site, they lead to a "Default.asp" file (with a capital D ) which lead to 404s. I went on the server and the only "default" file i see starts like this "default.asp" (with a lowercase d). But again, on the old server it works so I'm not understanding the issue.

To test i rename the "default.asp" to "Default.asp" and the links just dong go anywhere.

My question is, is a move from windows to windows not enough? am i missing something?
If i can be pointed in the right direction i appreciate it and thank you in advanced.

Comment: You need to make sure that the IIS server can run classic asp. It is within "Turn Windows features on or off" Then World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features > ASP

Comment: Filenames are case insensitive on IIS, the capital D shouldn't make any difference.  If you view your source code for the page on your new server you can see stuff like <%= request.QueryString("cat") %> - which means the server is treating .asp pages like flat html, which strongly suggests that Classic ASP is not enabled on your server as others have said.  Do you have remote desktop access?  If you do then this is quite straightforward with IIS manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your server does not support ASP or is missing some configs for it to work. The main thing to look at is to contact your host provider and ask it to enable ASP processing (as Tim B James explained in the comments).

If your hosting provider can't enable this for you, you will be out of luck and will need a new server that supports it.

TIP:
If you have access to a Plesk control pannel, going into the configuration section for this site gives you the ability to eneble or disable ASP, PHP, ASP.NET, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:-

- Install ASP on server - See here
  http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis
- Enable 32-Bit application in my Application pool in IIS
  https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx